# extended events blocked process report missing from sys.dm_xe_objects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, extended-events

Trying to create SERVER EVENT SESSION to capture blocked_process_report & xml_deadlock_report events to a file for later analysis with the following statement;

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [blocked_process] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.blocked_process_report(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,
           sqlserver.client_hostname,
           sqlserver.database_name)) ,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report (
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,
           sqlserver.client_hostname,
           sqlserver.database_name))
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
(SET filename = N'c:\temp\XEventSessions\blocked_process.xel',
     metadatafile = N'c:\temp\XEventSessions\blocked_process.xem',
     max_file_size=(65536),
     max_rollover_files=5)
WITH (MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 5SECONDS)
```

Receive the following error try to execute this statement;

> Msg 25623, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The event name, "sqlserver.blocked_process_report", is invalid, or the object could not be found**

A query in name order of **sys.dm_xe_objects**

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_xe_objects 
order by name;

Goes from binary_data to boolean, no "blocked_process_report" found, hence the error.

Current version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

I see other references to questions regarding this missing event but no responses.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check comments in this link:https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/extended-events-doesnt-hard/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the blocked_process_report was added as a traceable extended event in SQL Server 2012.

Since the extended events wizard(s) weren't added until SQL Server 2012, I would use the following query to view the available extended events:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_xe_objects AS Events
WHERE Events.object_type = 'event' AND Events.name LIKE '%blocked%'
ORDER BY Events.name;
```

Or even better read [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822788(v=sql.100).aspx) EXCEPTIONALLY good article by Jonathan Kehayias.

Answer (score 0):

Spent good chunk of time on the same issue and then finally managed to fix it. This error can occur due to two reasons:

1. Trying to create an extended event session on a SQL Server version that does not support that event i.e extended event `add_xact_outcome` exists in SQL Server 2019 but not in SQL Server 2012 so trying to create extended with `add_xact_outcome` in SQL Server 2012 will return this error.
2. This is tricky one. There is column in `sys.dm_xe_objects` called `capabilities_desc` and extended event session can ***ONLY*** be created for non-private extended events. Trying to create an extended event session for a private event will return this error too.

So, we need to add another `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_xe_objects AS Events
WHERE 
Events.object_type = 'event' 
AND 
Events.name LIKE '%blocked%'
AND
(Events.capabilities_desc <> 'private' OR Events.capabilities_desc is null)
ORDER BY Events.name;
```

Yes, `Events.capabilities_desc is null` is special case to handle null values as these values are not handled under `'private'`.

Importantly, if we try to create an extended event session via Wizard then list available of extended events does not show the private extended events for the same reason.

[Private extended events in SQL Server 2019, note events starting with `vdw_`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aadLH.png)

Now if we search, say, starting with `vdw_` and none of the event is shown

[Searching extended events while creating extended event via wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDTjU.png)

Found the same on Microsoft documentation:
[sys.dm_xe_objects (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-xe-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Private. The only object available for internal use, and that cannot
> be accessed via the CREATE/ALTER EVENT SESSION DDL. Audit events and
> targets fall into this category in addition to a small number of
> objects used internally.