# SQL Server 2008 blocked process report error in extended event

Tags: sql-server-2008, extended-events

Trying to create an extended event in SQL Server 2008 to capture the blocked process report.  Here is the script I am using:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [IA_BlockedProcesses] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.blocked_process_report(
ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,
            sqlserver.client_hostname,
            sqlserver.database_name)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report (
ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,
            sqlserver.client_hostname,
            sqlserver.database_name))
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
(SET filename = N'c:\Isaac\blocked_process.xel',
    metadatafile = N'c:\Isaac\blocked_process.xem',
    max_file_size = (65536),
    max_rollover_files = 5)
WITH (MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 5SECONDS)
GO
```

And when I run the script, I get this error:

> Msg 25623, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   The event name, "sqlserver.blocked_process_report", is invalid, or the object could not be found

I believe either I am not approaching this correctly, or the `blocked_process_report` is not available in this version of SQL Server.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_xe_objects 
WHERE name = 'blocked_process_report'
```

...there are no results.

Can anyone confirm for me definitively whether A) the blocked_process_report is indeed available in SQL Server 2008, and B) if my code above needs changed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mods - please close this as a duplicate.

After I posted this, then I was able to find this one:

[extended events blocked process report missing from sys.dm_xe_objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621484/extended-events-blocked-process-report-missing-from-sys-dm-xe-objects)

Looks like the blocked process report wasn't added as a traceable event until SQL Server 2012.

Thanks